# Meaning of 'against a society perceived as hostile"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It *[Love Bombing]* has also been described as psychological manipulation in order to create a feeling of unity within a group **against a society perceived as hostile.**

Source:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_bombing

Is the society perceiving the group as hostile or the group is perceiving the society as hostile? And the bold part is confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The society being hostile is a general perception.

It's saying that love bombing is a way to cope by creating a small group of people that love and value you as opposed to the society which is largely hostile.